# How to start flow in Visualforce Page with Apex-Defined input variables?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow

I try to start a Flow in Visualforce Page. This Flow has Apex-Defined type input variables.

My Apex-Defined Class code

```
public class OpportunityCloseConfig {

@AuraEnabled
public String currentType;

@AuraEnabled
public String avoidStage;    
    
}
```

My code for start flow

```
    $Lightning.use("c:LightningFlowApp", function() { 
       $Lightning.createComponent("lightning:flow", {"onstatuschange":handleFlowStatusChange},
          "flow-modal-content",
          function (component) {
              var flowName = flow.ApiName;                        
              var namespace = flow.NamespacePrefix;
              var apexObject = {
                  currentType: "Existing Customer - Downgrade",
                  avoidStage: "Closed Won"
              };
              var jsonString = JSON.stringify(apexObject);
              var inputVariables = [
                  {
                    config: apexObject
                  }
              ];                      
              component.startFlow(flowName, inputVariables);
          }
       );                   
    });
```

When I start flow I got follow error message on Screen, please see this image.

[image]

In Browser Console I also found error message "Error in $A.getCallback() [[object Object]]", does anyone know what's wrong in our code and how to fixed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start the flow from Visualforce page by using the below sample code -

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">  
   <flow:interview name="<NAME OF YOUR FLOW>" finishLocation="{!URLFOR('/003')}">  
     <apex:param name="currentType" value="Existing Customer - Downgrade" />  
     <apex:param name="avoidStage" value="Closed Won" />  
   </flow:interview>  
 </apex:page>
```

You can replace  with the actual flow api name.

Comment: Thanks for your idea, after discuss with my team, we decide call this a limitation.